# please locate WSEEAnnotationProcessor in weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

Under which jar this file WSEEAnnotationProcessor.java is available in weblogic 12c

full path to this file is weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor

Answer (score 0):

You will find your class in this library : $MW_HOME/oracle_common/modules/clients/com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxws-owsm-client.jar

Comment: Thanks Collin. In my weblogic version I can able to locate the file under $MW_HOME/wlserver/modules/clients/*.jar. It is available inside these 2 jars com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxrpc-client; com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxws-wlswss-client